# Launching Camera in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, html, android-camera

I am developing a Web Application (not Android Native App) for mobile browser. How do you launch the Android Native camera using a web application on the android browser?

I am currently referring to the following camera tutorial. It works on desktop browser but not on Chrome mobile browsers because only Opera Mobile 12.0 supports getUserMedia.
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera
http://caniuse.com/stream

I guess it is possible because if I access Facebook through my android browser (Not Facebook App), I can launch the phone native camera. Any help with the syntax to launch the android phone camera using HTML and Javascript will be great?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `intent://` URL that will trigger the native camera app. But that just launches this native app. There is no back channel that returns the taken picture to your web app.